# Play/Pause YouTube video in Pop Up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube, magnific-popup

I have a YouTube video contained in the following div:

```
<div id="playVideo" class="white-popup mfp-hide">
    <div class='embed-container'>
        <iframe id="video" src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/GYmW1u8YiQY?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer?rel=0' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the button element tied to opening it:

```
    <div class="ghost-button float">
        <a href="#playVideo" id="playPop" class="open-popup-link" style="color:black; font-size:24px; letter-spacing:2px; font-family: 'Pathway Gothic One', sans-serif;" onclick="">WATCH TRAILER</a>
    </div>
```

It's in a hidden pop-up made with the [magnific pop](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) library

I have the following javascript to play the video when a user clicks to open the pop-up:

```
    $('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
      type:'inline',
      midClick: true
    });

$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#playPop').on('click', function(ev){
            $('#video')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'playVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');   
        });

        $('.closebtn').on('click', function(ev2){
            $('#video')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');   
        });

        $('button .mfp-close').on('click', function(ev3){
            $('#video')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');   
        });

    });
```

Currently, the buttons to close the video work, but only after a user manually clicks to play. The video does not autoplay when they click to open the popup containing it. How can I get this to autoplay on click and stop when clicking another button?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the attribute autoplay="true" into the link source, demonstrated below.

src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/GYmW1u8YiQY?autoplay=true&enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer?rel=0'

Comment: The problem with setting the autoplay true attribute in the URL is that it hides the video when I close the button, but the element still exists, and essentially reloads and plays again from the beginning. I need to somehow either pause or stop it, or kill the DOM object and find a way to reload it. Trying to avoid needing to use the youtube API if I can help it.